# Can speakers wear out?

Tags: speakers

I'm looking at doing an overhaul of a classroom that hosts both spoken word and video presentations that sometimes include music. It currently has in-ceiling 8" Lowell 25 volt speakers (similar to their current model 810-T72) set at 1 watt. They are at least 20 years old.

Overall it sounds bad. Part of the issue is that the frequency response isn't good enough for the source signal. On those grounds alone, they need to be replaced.

What I'm specifically wondering about is, in this type of speaker, is there any chance of speaker components wearing out over time and thus affecting its performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely yes they can; depending on the construction both the cone and surround (if different material) will breakdown and degrade over time. The voice coil can also wear from heat and movement, or become damaged if debris gets into it. You can get quality replacement speakers cheap so I'd replace them. Parts Express is great.

Comment: Do you know of any resources that describe these issues? I'm not doubting you, and I guess I had intuited as much, but people who write the checks can sometimes need more proof than the word of the guy who is going to do the work.